# Convert urllib download to using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

How would I do the following using `requests` ?

```
urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://USER:pass@i.website.net/upload/file.csv', filepath)
```

If I try doing a `requests.get()`, I get an error that says `requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'ftp://`.

Comment: `requests` doesn't support FTP, it handles HTTP **only**.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html

Comment: You could try requests + [requests-ftp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-ftp) -- I haven't myself but it seems applicable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `requests` to download files over FTP. From the [`requests` documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> Requests is an Apache2 Licensed **HTTP library**, written in Python, for human beings.

The library *is* reasonably pluggable, and I notice that there is a [`requests-ftp` project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-ftp), but this is no more than a hack as no state is maintained. From the documentation:

> Does not provide:
>
> - Connection pooling! One new connection and multiple commands for each request, including authentication. Super inefficient.

The add-on is also not suitable for downloading large files as all data is loaded into memory, unlike a `requests.get('http://..', stream=True)` request.

Comment: That seems kind of silly that they wouldn't have `ftp` !

Comment: @David542: why is it silly? FTP is a different protocol. Browsers and `urllib` support it because they decided to support more than one protocol to allow for a wider range of URL schemes, but `requests` focuses on just HTTP.

Comment: @David542: some browsers (e.g. Opera, and in the past, the Netscape Navigator browser) support email too; you click on a `email:someaddress@someserver.com` link and send email. `urllib` doesn't support that. Then there are protocols such as `gopher` that [some browsers still support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_(protocol)#Native_Gopher_support). There is also `file://` which `urllib` does support for some requests (but not `urlretrieve()`, IIRC). But by focusing on just one protocol `requests` can greatly simplify the API for that usecase.